# Dropdown Rows with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a following table of grouped items:

[image: Grouped Items]

I want to display each item in dropdown rows under particular group. Would you mind to help how to make this with Angular JS?

I'm fetching all groups and items with a single JSON:

```
[
{"City":"NY",
"notes":"bla-bla",
"state":"Created",
,"description":"asdasdasda",
"locationId":1,
"waybillId":"",
"itemCount":3
"items":[{"itemId": "0001","status":"Created", "weight":23},
         {"itemId": "0002","status":"Created", "weight":23}
         {"itemId": "0003","status":"Created", "weight":23}
        ]

},

....

]
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Waybill</th>
            <th>Items</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="group in groupItems">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{group.city}}</td>
            <td>{{group.waybillId}}</td>
            <td>{{group.itemCount}}</td>
            <td>
                <span class="label label-success">{{group.state}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="">Ungroup</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For level 1,

`<tbody data-ng-repeat="storedata in storeDataModel.storedata" 
       data-ng-switch on="dayDataCollapse[$index]">`

For level 2, i.e. the second tr

`<tr data-ng-switch-when="true">`, in which you have the second level ng-repeat.

Check out the fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/VGgbq/`  for nested accordion like table.